# How to tell if only one player is found by selector?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How can I tell if only one person is found by a selector?
For example, this would be useful to see if there is only one person with a `playing` tag, and you would know when everyone has died but one so they can win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Command

```
execute @a[tag=playing] ~ ~ ~ testfor @a[tag=playing,rm=0.0000000000001]
```

## Explained

What we did was look for a player, then use that player to find another one of the same criteria, but with a `rm` argument which means the minimum distance (range) from the player we executed from. We put in a decimal with a bunch of spammed `0`s and then a `1` to find someone other than the player we're executing from. Without this, the player we execute from would detect him/herself. This block returns true if 2 or more players have the tag `playing`.

## Not Gate

We then take a comparator output from out command block and run it into a redstone torch, and above the torch have the command we want to run after. Follow Picture:
[image: Not Gate]
When two players are found, the comparator will turn on and turn off the torch. When two players are not found, the comparator will turn off and the torch will turn on, activating the command block above the torch.

## Work With `rm` Argument

*This section only applies to the specific situations where an `rm` argument is already being used. If your selector that you wanted to use doesn't include `rm`, ignore this.*
If you're already using the `rm` argument, we need a slightly modified approach. (For this example I will change the example selector from `@a[tag=playing]` to `@a[tag=playing,rm=5]`.) Note you will have to put an armor stand on the command block and name it or tag it, I will name the armor stand `testsel`. So, instead of doing something like `testfor@a[rm=5]`, we would do `execute@e[type=armor_stand,name=testsel]~~~testfor@a[rm=5]`.

### Command

From here we can change our previous command to:

```
execute @a[tag=playing,rm=5] ~ ~ ~ execute @a[tag=playing,rm=0.0000000001] ~ ~ ~ testfor @e[type=armor_stand,name=testsel,rm=5]
```

That command finds two people, outside the range of `5` and with the tag `playing` from the command block (`@a[tag=playing,rm=5]`).

### Explained

That command first executes off of someone at last of `5` distance and the tag `playing`. Then, we find someone else with the tag `playing`. We then look and see if our armor stand that was on top of our block is at least `5` distance away.

Comment: How else do you suggest a not gate?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 just last reply quick: With the addition of delays a while back, it isn’t bad since the “unpredictable” aspect can be shut out with delays. This is how you can do many things, such as wait for certain things in the game to run and render before continuing a command chain. Because of this, the unpredictable aspect is pretty much eliminated. I haven’t found a way to do this but like a day ago I [requested it as a command](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/360074414271-Add-not-command-) and no one in comments has an altern